# Spring REST Repositories inheritance null values

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

i have some trouble with mapping parent-child classes in Spring Rest Repositories. My case is that i need to authenticate both types of user with Spring Security, but i want also to be able to assign type specific attributes like Pets to Owner and salary for Employee. Is that good structure to accomplish such goal? If so, please help with that problem.

I already made it to insert into one table differentiating one from eachother with dtype column, but cant manage to insert any other values than dtype.

I'm using newest Spring Boot (default JSON mapper) with MS SQL.

This is my payload for POST request:

```
{
    "username": "admin",  // null in db
    "firstName": "Delacruz", // null in db
    "lastName": "House", // null in db
    "dtype": "Owner" // present in db
}
```

This is my class structure:

Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "user", collectionResourceRel = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Parent class - User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property="dtype")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name="Owner", value=Owner.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name="Employee", value=Employee.class)})
@RestResource(path="user")
public abstract class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String username;
// rest of properties
}
```

Employee - first child class

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee extends User {

    private String type = "EMPLOYEE";

    @Column
    @Enumerated
    private EmployeeType employeeType;

    @Column
    private LocalDate dateOfEmployment;
    //rest of properties
}
```

Owner - another child class

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@Entity
public class Owner extends User{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Pet> pets;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding following constructor (accordingly to Owner) to subclasses resolved issue:

```
@JsonCreator
public Employee(
        @JsonProperty(value = "username") String username,
        @JsonProperty(value = "firstName") String firstName,
        @JsonProperty(value = "lastName") String lastName,
        @JsonProperty(value = "password") String password,
        @JsonProperty(value = "email") String email,
        @JsonProperty(value = "phoneNumber") String phoneNumber
) {
    super(username, firstName, lastName, password, email, phoneNumber);
}
```